Who do other Kshatriya groups like the Kambojas descend from?
Who do other Kshatriya groups like the Kambojas descend from?
Do they also come from the Solar and Lunar dynasties?
Or are they of some other lineage? There appear to be many Kshatriya in the periphery of the Kurus, but I cannot find what their origin may have been. In the case of the Kambojas, they seem to be linked with Asura. But surely there must be a proper origin for these other groups of warriors.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
